# Highlight Rows in an excel document

Tags: vb.net, windows, excel, forms

Is there a way to highlight/fill the cells in row x a given colour from a visual basic application? I can read and write to cells but can't find syntax to format cells or entire rows if possible.

Edit:
code for Read/Write

```
Dim APP As New Excel.Application
        Dim worksheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim workbook As Excel.Workbook
        workbook = APP.Workbooks.Open(InputFile)
        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
```

Read:

```
Arr(i, 0) = worksheet.Cells(rowcount, 14).value
```

Write:

```
worksheet.Cells(row, Col).value = Arr(i, 2)
```

Comment: please post your code for read\write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah you can. Use code like:

`Range("A1").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

You can set range like.. `Range("A1:A10")`

For all cells in row(1):

`Rows(1).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)`

@Edit

Also possible to set colors via *ColorIndex* for example:

`Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 37`